# Stream on DynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have a DynamoDB table. When I check the Overview tab for the table on AWS Web Console, I see two options to enable streams.

1. Manage Streams to Kinesis
2. Manage DynamoDB Stream.

How these two streams are different from one another?

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB offers two streaming models for change data capture: Kinesis Data Streams for DynamoDB and DynamoDB Streams.

For the differences between the two and to help you choose the right solution for your application, please refer to Streaming Options for Change Data Capture [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/streamsmain.html)